# Repairing of electronic throttle control

Tags: throttle, opel, throttle-position-sensor

I am the owner of an Opel Astra G Caravan (This is the European name, don't know how it is in USA) from year 2007. It has an 1.4 Twinport engine Z14XEP and a manual gear.

A few days ago I noticed that my car is going crazy at high rpms (2500+) and the yellow Check Engine sign appeared on dashboard, but engine doesn't stall, but it is working in a strange way after this with big vibrations. (If I am stopping the engine and starting again the problem is dissapearing)

So I decided to arrive home and have a look into Throttle Body, bought a carb. cleaner, removed it from engine and cleaned it. After putting it back I decided to give it a try, and voila, the same problem was there. And now sometimes on my way to work the engine does the same thing, and if I am looking under the pipe that comes from air filter to the body the Throttle butterfly is blocked in full open position.

So is there a way to repair the sensor? 
because I don't really want to change the body, because it costs me in my country around 350 Euro for a new one

Comment: the issue you're facing is almost certainly due to the ETB malfunctioning as you've rightly identified. Since the butterfly remains open, the engine is controlled using fueling and ignition timing alone resulting in the symptoms you're facing. You'l need to now ascertain what is causing the the ETB to malfunction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, there was some problems with electronics of throttle control, it costs me about 80 euros (100$) to repair it.